# Fazer SELECT retornar só um trecho da string

Tags: sql

Preciso fazer uma consulta que traga apenas um trecho da string. Pensei em usar a função SUBSTR() mas não consegui.
Ex: coluna sendo algo como [abcd efg hig; efg hig abcd; jkl juh hig] e eu quero trazer na consulta apenas a quantidade de linhas com "hig".

Comment: Você quer filtrar a sua consulta com um where? Tem um exemplo do que você tentou fazer?

Comment: [Edit] a postagem com um [mcve] e um breve exemplo de dados e resultados esperados pode ajudar bastante.

Comment: Sim, quero filtrar com um where. Mas eu preciso que a consulta traga a quantidade de linhas com uma determinada substring. Não sei está confuso ainda

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente sua pergunta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sua_tabela WHERE seu_campo LIKE '%hig%';
```

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas não compreendi bem o que ele quer... Mas acho que precisa do % nesse like.